# Communication Usb Device in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

In Android, I am using UsbManager and UsbDevice to connect to the device. I want to communicate with the UsbDevice in Flutter but do not know how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#example-calling-platform-specific-ios-and-android-code-using-platform-channels might be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Hey i have the same issues, but i found this flutter_usb_write. It can be useful but it's a very new plug-in so i'm testing it but I'haven't already the solution. If you want you can try to use it i'll do too, and if i found something interesting i'll tell you.
[flutter_usb_write](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_usb_write#-readme-tab-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When posting answers that is primarily a link, you have to show how is it a useful solution, (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and maybe quote a code snippet from the resource.